# How can I find the symmetry group of a $4$-D 5-cell?

Tags: group-theory

To keep this simple, lets ignore the 4D equivalent of flipping/mirroring and just focus on rotational symmetry. I know that an equilateral triangle has the rotational symmetry group $S_3$, tetrahedron: $A_4$. However I'm struggling to find it for a 5-cell.

I'm relatively new to group theory so apologies for any inconsistencies in knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rotational and reflection symmetries of any simplex is $S_n$ where $n$ is the number of elements in the simplex. For rotations alone you take only the even permutations contained in $S_n$ because each rotation is equivalent to a pair of reflections. So, you're left with $A_n$. Note $A_3=Z_3$ for $n=3$.